# VichUploaderBundle, Form\Type\VichImageType Error Produccion

Tags: php, symfony, vps, vichuploaderbundle

Estoy realizando el deployment de un proyecto, el desarrollo es en **Symfony 5.1**, usando el **easyadmin-bundle 3.1**, y el **vich/uploader-bundle 1.15**. De manera local el proyecto funciona sin problemas, pero en produccion me da el siguiente error cuando intento **crear un producto**

> An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType": The options "upload_dir", "upload_filename" do not exist.

[image: https://ibb.co/vdjwQ6V]

El unico lugar donde encuentro el **upload_dir,** es dentro del vendor.
[image: https://ibb.co/28Z5hCH]

Mi entidad

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ColoresRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class Colores
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="colores", fileNameProperty="thumbnail")
     */
    private $thumbnailFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getThumbnailFile()
    {
        return $this->thumbnailFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $thumbnailFile
     */
    public function setThumbnailFile($thumbnailFile): void
    {
        $this->thumbnailFile = $thumbnailFile;

        if($thumbnailFile) {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $thumbnail
     */
    public function setThumbnail($thumbnail): void
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

}
```

Mi Dashboard

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\CrudUrlGenerator;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Colores;




class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    /**
     * @Route("admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $routeBuilder = $this->get(CrudUrlGenerator::class)->build();

        return $this->redirect($routeBuilder->setController(ColoresCrudController::class)->generateUrl());
    }

    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Test Site');
    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::section('DESTACADOS');
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Colores', 'fa fa-paint-brush', Colores::class);

}
```

Mi Crud controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Colores;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class ColoresCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Colores::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('nombre'),
            ImageField::new('thumbnailFile')
                ->setFormType(VichImageType::class)->onlyOnForms(),
            ImageField::new('thumbnail')
                ->setBasePath('/images/colores')->hideOnForm()
        ];
    }

}
```

vich_uploader.yaml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        colores:
            uri_prefix: /images/colores
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/colores'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme con este problema.

Comment: Por favor revisa [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y después edita la pregunta para colocar el código como texto, es difícil tratar de analizarlo en una imagen.

Comment: Modifique el post, espero que sea mas simple de analizar, gracias por el consejo, si hay algo mas que mejorar, te agradeceria que me informes.

Answer (score 0):

He tenido exactamente el mismo problema, he añadido a composer el require de la última versión y por ultimo ejecutando composer install.

```
"vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.15"
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, mi solucion fue volver a la version 3.1.7 del easyAdmin , porque vi que esta reportado en su github, que el error ocurre en la version 3.1.8.